# Windows vista shows ISO file as ZIP!

Tags: iso, windows-vista, zip

When I download the ISO file, my system shows the file as a zip file and not as an ISO. I have tried to burn the file as an image to a DVD but my laptop will not bootup from the CD. 
Setting in the BIOS are ok. So I guess the problem is with the ISO file or the way I burned the CD.

I have follwed the instructions on the site for downloading and burning an ISO image to CD. And I guess that my problem is with the file association in windows Vista.

Any ideas and suggestions are welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One thing you're definitely going to want to make sure of is that the .iso image you are burning is bootable. What program are you using to burn?

As far as your OS showing a .iso file as a .zip, that's in the settings of your archive manager. For instance, I use WinRAR which has the capability of recognizing a .iso file as an archive. Normally this setting is chosen during the Installation Setup of the archive manager. Depending on which one you're using though, it may have been automatically configured. Refer to your utility's help files for configuring recognized file extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Open Winzip. Go to `Option` menu `> Settings`. Choose last Tab `integration`. Uncheck `iso`. Close all.

You will able to open .iso file with burning tool rather than winzip.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download another program to burn images, and it will take over the file association and provide many great features. For example, [ImgBurn](http://imgburn.com) will take over the file association, and you can also run the program, pick to burn to a disk, and then browse for the image. IMGburn also provides many useful features you may enjoy, especially on professional equipment.

> Note: The author of this post has no connection to ImgBurn. ObsessiveFOSS uses it once in a while and likes it, but nothing more.